# What's the postDelayed() uses in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, handler

As I know postDelayed() have two argument runnable and duration delay.
What actually does below code in kotlin:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
            sendMessage(MSG, params.id)
            taskFinished(params, false)
        }, duration)
```

Here 1st is two function calling and 2nd is duration delay. Where is runnable? Does this something like lambda for kotlin? Any anyone please explain this?

Comment: did this answer your question?

Answer (score 55):

The `Handler::postDelay` documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) and shows that the method is defined as follows:

```
boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

In idiomatic Kotlin APIs, we would change the order of both parameters and have the function type (i.e. SAM `Runnable`) as the last argument so that it could be passed outside the parentheses. But sometimes we just have to deal with it, let's have a look at your example:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            sendMessage(MSG, params.id)
            taskFinished(params, false)
        }, duration)
```

The first argument wrapped in curly braces is a lambda which becomes the `Runnable` thanks to [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). You could make this more obvious by extracting it to a local variable:

```
val r = Runnable {
     sendMessage(MSG, params.id)
     taskFinished(params, false)
}
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(r, duration)
```

Comment: Instantiating Handler with the empty constructor is deprecated now. Initialize it, for example, with Looper, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477706/8716408

Answer (score 29):

`Handler()` is depreciated now in place of it we have to use `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                },200)
```