# What do I use now that Handler() is deprecated?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-handler

How do I fix the deprecation warning in this code? Alternatively, are there any other options for doing this?

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    context?.let {
        //code
    }
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Just use new before the code.  new Handler().postDelayed({
    context?.let {
        //code
    }
}, 3000)

Answer (score 703, accepted):

Only the parameterless constructor is deprecated, it is now preferred that you specify the `Looper` in the constructor via the `Looper.getMainLooper()` method.

### Use it for Java

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your Code
    }
}, 3000);
```

### Use it for Kotlin

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    // Your Code
}, 3000)
```

Source : [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler())

Comment: Straight forward...

Comment: what is getMainLooper()?

Comment: @UNREAL Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread of the application. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper#getMainLooper()

Answer (score 97):

From API level 30, there are 2 constructors that are deprecated.

- [Handler()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler())
- [Handler(Handler.Callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler(android.os.Handler.Callback))

Google explains the reason below.

> Implicitly choosing a Looper during
> Handler construction can lead to bugs where operations are silently
> lost (if the Handler is not expecting new tasks and quits), crashes
> (if a handler is sometimes created on a thread without a Looper
> active), or race conditions, where the thread a handler is associated
> with is not what the author anticipated. Instead, use an Executor or
> specify the Looper explicitly, using Looper#getMainLooper, {link
> android.view.View#getHandler}, or similar. If the implicit thread
> local behavior is required for compatibility, use new
> Handler(Looper.myLooper(), callback) to make it clear to readers.

**Solution 1:** Use an [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor)

**1.** Execute code in the main thread.

**Java**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in the main thread. 
Executor mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);

// Execute a task in the main thread
mainExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // You code logic goes here.
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in the main thread.
val mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)

// Execute a task in the main thread
mainExecutor.execute {
    // You code logic goes here.
}
```

**2.** Execute code in a background thread

**Java**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in a background thread.
ScheduledExecutorService backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// Execute a task in the background thread.
backgroundExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code logic goes here.
    }
});

// Execute a task in the background thread after 3 seconds.
backgroundExecutor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code logic goes here
    }
}, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in a background thread.
val backgroundExecutor: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

// Execute a task in the background thread.
backgroundExecutor.execute {
    // Your code logic goes here.
}

// Execute a task in the background thread after 3 seconds.
backgroundExecutor.schedule({
    // Your code logic goes here
}, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

**Note:** Remember to shut down the executor after using.

```
backgroundExecutor.shutdown(); // or backgroundExecutor.shutdownNow();
```

**3.** Execute code in a background thread and update UI on the main thread.

**Java**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in the main thread. 
Executor mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);

// Create an executor that executes tasks in a background thread.
ScheduledExecutorService backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// Execute a task in the background thread.
backgroundExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code logic goes here.
        
        // Update UI on the main thread
        mainExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // You code logic goes here.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create an executor that executes tasks in the main thread. 
val mainExecutor: Executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)

// Create an executor that executes tasks in a background thread.
val backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

// Execute a task in the background thread.
backgroundExecutor.execute {
    // Your code logic goes here.

    // Update UI on the main thread
    mainExecutor.execute {
        // You code logic goes here.
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Specify a Looper explicitly by using one of the following constructors.

- [Handler(Looper)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler(android.os.Looper))
- [Handler(Looper, Handler.Callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler(android.os.Looper,%20android.os.Handler.Callback))

**1.** Execute code in the main thread

**1.1.** Handler with a Looper

**Java**

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

**Kotlin**

```
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

**1.2** Handler with a Looper and a Handler.Callback

**Java**

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        // Your code logic goes here.
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), Handler.Callback {
    // Your code logic goes here.
    true
})
```

**2.** Execute code in a background thread

**2.1.** Handler with a Looper

**Java**

```
// Create a background thread that has a Looper
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();

// Create a handler to execute tasks in the background thread.
Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create a background thread that has a Looper
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("HandlerThread")
handlerThread.start()


// Create a handler to execute tasks in the background thread.
val backgroundHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
```

**2.2.** Handler with a Looper and a Handler.Callback

**Java**

```
// Create a background thread that has a Looper
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();

// Create a handler to execute taks in the background thread.
Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        // Your code logic goes here.
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create a background thread that has a Looper
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("HandlerThread")
handlerThread.start()


// Create a handler to execute taks in the background thread.
val backgroundHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper, Handler.Callback {
    // Your code logic goes here.
    true
})
```

**Note:** Remember to release the thread after using.

```
handlerThread.quit(); // or handlerThread.quitSafely();
```

**3.** Execute code in a background thread and update UI on the main thread.

**Java**

```
// Create a handler to execute code in the main thread
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// Create a background thread that has a Looper
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();

// Create a handler to execute in the background thread
Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        // Your code logic goes here.
        
        // Update UI on the main thread.
        mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
            }
        });
        
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Create a handler to execute code in the main thread
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

// Create a background thread that has a Looper
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("HandlerThread")
handlerThread.start()

// Create a handler to execute in the background thread
val backgroundHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper, Handler.Callback {
    // Your code logic goes here.

    // Update UI on the main thread.
    mainHandler.post {
        
    }
    true
})
```

Comment: awesome stuff ! Cheers

Comment: Genius!! Best Answer

Comment: Hello sir, How to get message in kotlin, thank you.

Answer (score 79):

If you want to avoid the null check thing in Kotlin (`?` or `!!`) you can use `Looper.getMainLooper()` if your `Handler` is working with some UI related thing, like this:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
   Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "LOOPER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}, 3000)
```

Note: use `requireContext()` instead of `this@MainActivity` if you are using fragment.

Answer (score 29):

The deprecated function is that constructor for Handler.  Use `Handler(Looper.myLooper()) .postDelayed(runnable, delay)` instead

Comment: This doesn't work in Kotlin because `Looper.myLooper()` returns a `Looper?` (possible null value).

Comment: @EllenSpertus Then add in a null check, or use Looper.myLooper()!! which will throw an NPE if its null.  If you're on a thread with a looper it will return non-null.  If not, it will return null and should throw an exception in any language.

Answer (score 24):

Consider using coroutines

```
scope.launch {
    delay(3000L)
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Inside `Activity` or `Fragment`: `lifecycleScope.launch { delay(3000L) }`

Answer (score 22):

Using lifecycle scope this is more easy. Inside activity or fragment.

```
 lifecycleScope.launch {
     delay(2000)
     // Do your stuff
 }
```

or use handler

```
        Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
```

Comment: How to avoid the !! operator ?

Comment: It can be null so you have to write !! to ensure it is not null

Comment: doing !! can cause exception as looper can be null nad Handler requires a non-nulable value

Answer (score 18):

I have **3 solutions**:

1. Specify the Looper explicitly:

   ```
   Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
       // code
   }, duration)
   ```
2. Specify the implicit thread local behavior:

   ```
   Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
       // code
   }, duration)
   ```
3. using `Thread`:

   ```
   Thread({
       try{
           Thread.sleep(3000)
       } catch (e : Exception) {
           throw e
       }
        // code
   }).start()
   ```

Answer (score 13):

`Handler()` and `Handler(Handler.Callback callback)` constructors are deprecated. Because those can leads to bugs & crashes. Use Executor or Looper explicitly.

**For Java**

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //do your work here
   }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 10):

use this

```kotlin
Looper.myLooper()?.let {
    Handler(it).postDelayed({
        //Your Code
    },2500)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use Executor instead of handler for more info [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor).
To achieve post delay use `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
};
worker.schedule(runnable, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: This is not a bad answer, in fact even [google recommends this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler()).

Answer (score 8):

```
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Handler

inline fun delay(delay: Long, crossinline completion: () -> Unit) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        completion()
    }, delay)
}
```

Example:

```
delay(1000) {
    view.refreshButton.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Provide a looper in the Handler Constructor

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Variable for Handler and Runnable then use it like this.

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(runnable = () -> {
        // Do delayed stuff here
         handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }, delay);
```

Also You need to remove callbacks in onDestroy()

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the document (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler()):

> Implicitly choosing a Looper during Handler construction can lead to bugs where operations are silently lost (if the Handler is not expecting new tasks and quits), crashes (if a handler is sometimes created on a thread without a Looper active), or race conditions, where the thread a handler is associated with is not what the author anticipated. Instead, use an Executor or specify the Looper explicitly, using Looper#getMainLooper, {link android.view.View#getHandler}, or similar. If the implicit thread local behavior is required for compatibility, use new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) to make it clear to readers.

We should stop using the constructor without a Looper, and specify a Looper instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Coroutines Kotlin**

```
private val SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT_CONST: Long = 3000

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT_CONST)
        goToIntro()
    }

}

private fun goToIntro(){
    startActivity(Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
```

Comment: I think there is no difference between GlobalScope vs Handler. The GlobalScope doesn't aware the lifecycle(except the app process). In my opinion, lifecycle scope or custom scope is more convenient way according to the GlobalScope.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea use this structure in Kotlin

```
companion object Run {
   fun after(delay: Long, process: () -> Unit) {
      Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
          process()
      }, delay)
   }
}
```

Later call as

```
Run.after(SPLASH_TIME_OUT) {
   val action = SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToLogin()
   v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Java Answer**

I wrote a method to use easily. You can use this method directly in your project. *delayTimeMillis* can be 2000, it means that this code will run ***after*** 2 seconds.

```
private void runJobWithDelay(int delayTimeMillis){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //todo: you can call your method what you want.
        }
    }, delayTimeMillis);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this one

Code:

```
Handler(Looper.myLooper() ?: return).postDelayed({
           // Code what do you want
        }, 3000)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The handler() etc code is generated by the Android Studio 4.0.1 when a Fullscreen Activity, for example, is created from scratch. I know that we are being encouraged to use Kotlin, which I do, but from time to time I use sample projects to get an idea going.
It seems strange that we are chastised by AS when AS actually generates the code. It might be a useful academic activity to go through the errors and fix them but maybe AS could generate new clean code for us enthusiasts...

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Android, instead of

```
Handler handler;
handler = new Handler();
```

just write

```
Handler handler;
handler = new Handler(Looper.MyLooper());
```

the rest of the code is fine.