# How to handle deprecated Handler in android

Tags: android, handler, deprecated

Previously this code worked perfect.

Now its is showing android.os.handler is deprecated.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
        break;
        }
    }
```

How can we resolve this issue.

Comment: `Handler` is not deprecated. Look more closely at the error message. That particular constructor is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler().

Comment: check this answer it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851895/5773037

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned by Mike in the comments, `Handler` is not deprecated. The way of creating an object of Handler using `new Handler()` is deprecated.

As per the documentation, using `new Handler()` can lead to bugs. So you should specify a looper for the handler explicitly. Looper must not be null.

Refer the code:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
        break;
        }
    }
```