# Handler run function error kotlin for first time

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do a `Handler (). PostDelayed` in kotlin using java as the base, however this time I get an error, could someone answer why this happens? And what would be the most up-to-date solution? And for what reason are there functions or classes that appear crossed out, as in this case Handler ()?:

```
Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {

            override fun run()
            {
                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
                var isFirstTime : Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT.toLong())
```

[image]

Comment: refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517194/how-to-handle-deprecated-handler-in-android/63517606#63517606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of lambda in Kotlin. below code will work:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
                var isFirstTime : Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT.toLong())
```

Also refer to my answer here: [How to handle deprecated Handler in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517194/how-to-handle-deprecated-handler-in-android/63517606#63517606)