# How to delay some action in Android so that a task completes after a set Delay?

Tags: android, multithreading, action, android-task

I am trying to develop an app in Android which has a few actions that need to be executed after a set period of time.

Anything which I can do to fulfil this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using java to code in android Studio then I suggest you to use the Handler, that will execute your action after a determined span of time

In your activity's `onCreate` method do this:

```
 int any_delay_in_ms = 1000; //1Second interval
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        //TODO Perform your action here
    }, any_delay_in_ms);
```

Answer (score 5):

All the answer are correct but initiating handler like below is deprecated.

```
new Handler()
```

You need to provide a looper to the handler object. So use below snippet:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
   // do something
}, 1000)
```

Looper.getMainLooper() will ensure that code written in that block runs on UI thread.

More details in my other answer: [How to handle deprecated Handler in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517194/how-to-handle-deprecated-handler-in-android/63517606#63517606)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use libraries, then handler will be enough

```
Handler().postDelayed({
   // do smth after delay
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Handler is deprecated now.