# Handler() is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to update a seekbar every second in background using **Kotlin** & **Coroutines** but It says Handler() is deprecated use it with looper and i am confused how to use **handler**, **looper** and **kotlin** **coroutines**

The code i tried to make it work

```
val myHandler: Handler = Handler()
myHandler.postAtTime(asyncSeekBar(), 1000)
```

Here showing Handler() is deprecated

**asyncSeekBar()**

```
private fun asyncsSeekBar() {
        CoroutineScope(Default).launch {
            updateSeekBar()
        }
    }
```

but asyncSeekBar should be Runnable
therefore showing and error

> Type mismatch. Required: Runnable Found: Unit

***If there is any other way of doing it with more simpler way, please suggest***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I use now that Handler() is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023968/what-do-i-use-now-that-handler-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) for this to run every second:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (true) {
        delay(1000)
        updateSeekBar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Handler when you have coroutines?

```kotlin
scope.launch {
    delay(1000)  // 1000ms
    asyncSeekBar()
}
```

The error you're getting is because you're not passing an implementation of `Runnable` interface, you are instead calling the function and returning the return value which is nothing (`Unit`) to the postAtTime().