# What is the alternative for using a Handler to remove a Firebase DatabaseReference listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, runnable, android-handler

I'm following along this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_22.html) for using Android architecture components with Firebase Realtime Database. Currently, I am at the part where I use a `Handler` to schedule the removal of a database listener by posting a `Runnable` callback that performs the removal on a two-second delay after the `LiveData` becomes inactive.

This is what I have (the Kotlin equivalent of the Java code from the blog):

```
class FirebaseQueryLiveData(ref: DatabaseReference) : LiveData<DataSnapshot>() {
    private val query: Query = ref
    private val listener: MyValueEventListener = MyValueEventListener()

    private var listenerRemovePending = false

    private val handler: Handler = Handler()

    private val removeListener = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            query.removeEventListener(listener)
            listenerRemovePending = false
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener)
        } else {
            query.addValueEventListener(listener)
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000)
        query.removeEventListener(listener)
    }

    private inner class MyValueEventListener : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            value = snapshot
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is `Handler` has been deprecated, so I shouldn't be using this in my code. How do I modify my code to use the suggested alternative of a `Handler`?

Comment: Have you looked into Coroutines? I think you can run this example using a coroutine that runs on the main i.e. `Dispatchers.Main` thread

Comment: Handler is not deprecated, but some constructors are deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023968/what-do-i-use-now-that-handler-is-deprecated